# Chrome extension context menu doesn't work on YouTube HTML5 players

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, youtube, html5-video, vimeo

I made a context menu by using chrome api(http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html#contextMenus) to develop a chrome extension.

when I right click on a Vimeo HTML5 video player, the context shows up.
but on a YouTube HTML5 video, it doesn't show up. (I've enabled HTML5 player at YouTube)

why is this difference occurred even they use the same HTML5 player?

perhaps Vimeo uses another video platform instead of HTML5 player?

please answer me :-)

Comment: Can you show your extension code? Could you show a screenshot of the contextmenu on YouTube? Does it say something like Flash?

Comment: sure! I sent you the e-mail. check it out :D

Comment: Hi @user. You should edit the question and the details in the post. Having a complete question helps others with the understanding of your question, and any answers that posted to it. For more information, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: In the screenshots you've send me, I can clearly see that the YouTube video is played using the Flash player. Have you already enabled HTML5 at http://www.youtube.com/html5 ? If not, try it. If yes, then the specific video was probably not available on YouTube's HTML5 player.

Comment: Sorry, I sent you again. I've already enabled HTML5 player on Youtube. but even on HTML5 video, it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah yes, YouTube intercepts the contextmenu event and renders a custom context menu using HTML. You could add your item to this menu using [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) (use mutation observers to detect the presence of the menu).

Comment: I don't know what is the 'mutation observer' ;_; Could you explain me about how can I do more detail?

Comment: Please use Google or Stack Overflow search. I've given the terms for the relevant technologies, doing one Google search would have given you access to a wealth of information.